# Salesforce Data Model for Account addresses

Tags: account, address, data-model

I'm confused about Salesforce's direction on setting up a many-to-many relationship between Accounts and addresses.

Typically, a many-to-many relationship requires a junction object between the two primary objects (which would keep the data normalized).

However, looking at the standard objects in my org's schema, I'm seeing (1) some (standard) address fields on the Account object, (2) a separate (standard) Address object (with no direct connection to the Account object) and (3) a 'Location' object, that has a Master-Detail with Address, but only a Lookup relationship with Accounts(??)

Bottom line:  Which method does SF recommend when your org has many Accounts per Address, and many possible Addresses for each Account?  (Note: My org is using both Person Accounts and Business Accounts, for the 'right' reasons)

Comment: Out of the box, there's no direct match. Getting into the data model weeds is a classic sign of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if would help to know what you're trying to achieve from a business/functional perspective. Take a look at NPSP model (not limited to non-profits, despite its name), it does much of what you're after   https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/nonprofit-success-pack-administration-basics/understand-the-npsp-data-model

Answer (score 1):

The `Address` object is a child of `Location` and `Location` is an object used by Field Service Lightning

> [Location](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_location.htm)
>
> Represents a warehouse, service vehicle, work site, or other element of the region where your team performs field service work. In API version 49.0 and later, you can associate activities with specific locations. Activities, such as the tasks and events related to a location, appear in the activities timeline when you view the location detail page. Also in API version 49.0 and later, Work.com users can view Employees as a related list on Location records. In API version 51.0 and later, this object is available for Omnichannel Inventory and represents physical locations where inventory is available for fulfilling orders.

As such, these two standard objects apply to a specific licensed product that is outside of the normal Platform, Sales Cloud and Service Cloud licenses that most admins deal with